# Button one spreadsheet updates another spreadsheet over the internet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two excel spreadsheets. One is on my computer called "alan.xlsm" and the other file called "mick.xlsm" is on a colleagues computer in a different location (both have internet access).  On my spreadsheet there is a button.  When I click that button I want it to put "TEST" into cell "A1" on my colleagues workbook "mick.xlsm".

I have scoured google with no success on where to even begin.  Am I just trying something that is not practical?

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: Easiest approach would be a shared folder using onedrive or sharepoint. Then the 'other' spreadsheet is accessible via a filepath like any other.

Comment: See what you are saying... if no other option is available then it may have to be the only way.  Appreciate the idea.

Comment: A spreadsheet can't just listen on the internet from a message from another spreadsheet. you need something in the middle that they both communicate with, there are lots of ways of doing it but would depend on what you have available to you.  The whole architecture you would need to make this sort of thing work is kinda out of scope of a stackoverflow question/answer. Depending on what problem you're actually trying to solve, the right answer might be use smartsheets or google spreadsheets then you eliminate the messaging problem entirely.

Comment: You got access to a SharePoint instance by chance?

Comment: I think I could get access to one for sure.